# CakePHP: Can I use containable to include records from the same table in find() results?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

My modle has a hasMany relationship with its self because certain records are "parents" to other records in that same table.

I'm having no trouble returning the associated records with $this->Model->find('all'...) from inside the controller but the same thing does not work when I use it inside a *different* model's controller. I believe this is a job for [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) but I can't get it to work. I don't see errors, but the associated records don't appear (just the one parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se up your model like this and you should then be able to use the containable behaviour

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

  public $hasMany = array(
    'Children'=>array(
       'className'=>'MyModel',
       'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    )
  );

  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent'=>array(
       'className'=>'MyModel',
       'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    )
  );

}
```

Comment: That looks great! But I want to double-check: will this work even if the class names (Children, MyModel, etc) are all the *same* model?

Comment: All the places I've used `MyModel` can be the same model.  The `Children` and `Parent` are aliases and can be anything you want them to be

Comment: This works! But there is still one mystery: my models were basically set up as you (correctly) advised. The problem turned out to be related to a `$this->OtherModel->contain(...)` appearing higher up in the same controller. Does this make sense to you? I didn't see anything in the book about "cross-pollination" across models of the `contain()` method.